# Saving documents only to sharepoint document libraries?

Tags: 2013, security, office-web-apps

what we need is to deny users to create documents on local computers and create any document in sharepoint document libraries. I know. it's strange idea, but it's not mine.

First, we'll delete office applications from computers and users will have only office web apps in sharepoint.

Is there any way to deny users save documents from office web apps to local computer? So, they will have to save it to sharepoint document library.

Or is there any way to automatically save documents from office web apps to some sharepoint document library without disabling saving to local computer?

Or maybe we can just hide Save As menu in office web apps some way?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but it may be too wide a strike. If you deny you users to use any other browser than Internet Explorer, you could set a group policy that denies file download.

[image]

Than even if users try to download files, they cant when they hit any download link in Office Web Apps

[image]

But just because you can, doesn't mean that you should. I'm not comfortable implementing such a rule. Users can take screenshots of content anyway, and your restricted data could be exposed as long as it's shown on a screen.

Comment: The users will not able to download any file.

Comment: @RomanA. True, and that's why I think its a too wide suggestion myself...

Comment: I would look into IRM policies on the document library before thinking about a group policy

Comment: @EricAlexander True Eric! That's a better way to prevent download. But I don't know (yet) if you could use Ctrl-A Ctrl-C and past it in notepad. See more on IRM here Roman: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Apply-Information-Rights-Management-to-a-list-or-library-3bdb5c4e-94fc-4741-b02f-4e7cc3c54aa1

Comment: @EricAlexander Thanks for advices.  
After discussing with customer here is updated task - We can allow users to save documents to local computer, but we need to auto save documents to some sharepoint library. Any ideas?

Comment: @BennySkogberg Thanks for advices. After discussing with customer here is updated task - We can allow users to save documents to local computer, but we need to auto save documents to some sharepoint library. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there are 2 main questions here

1. Deny users saving files to local drive. Quick answer is no, as users at some point will have to write some files. Limiting saving only the office files I don't  think this is possible.

But what you could do is to set default save location on the office clients through the GPO. 
This setting may help as well:
User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Explorer > Prevent access to drives from My Computer

Have a look at this thread it should give you some pointers.

https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/262098-do-not-allow-users-to-save-keep-files-on-their-desktop

2. Or maybe we can just hide Save As menu in office web apps some way? Modifying the OWA is limited you cannot do much there. It may be possible to do some rewrites on the loadbalancer to remove some buttons (I have done something similar but for the BI report viewer that was in silverlight).

Comment: After discussing with customer here is updated task - We can allow users to save documents to local computer, but we need to auto save documents to some sharepoint library. Any ideas?